fancyhdr footer is rendered on page delayed when using landscape mid document
I got a document where there are some pages in landscape mode.
I managed to rotate those pages with setting \paperwidth, pdfpagewidth and \textwidth (and some others).
My problem is that the footer on page 2 does not appear. It is rendered on page 3 in the correct position. On page 4 when switching back to portrait it has still the spacing from the page top like the page is in landscape mode.
I think my problem is that I do no clear/flush something for the current page when rotating, and it only gets updated with the next page.
MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
% \usepackage{showframe}


\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{Some Header Text}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\newcommand{\newvar}[2]{
  \newlength#1
  \setlength#1{#2}
}

\newvar{\initialPaperWidth}{\paperwidth}
\newvar{\initialPaperHeight}{\paperheight}
\newvar{\initialTextWidth}{\textwidth}
\newvar{\initialTextHeight}{\textheight}



\newenvironment{landscape}{
  \newpage
  \pagestyle{fancy}

  \paperwidth=\initialPaperHeight
  \paperheight=\initialPaperWidth
  \pdfpagewidth=\initialPaperHeight
  \pdfpageheight=\initialPaperWidth
  
  \textwidth=\initialTextHeight
  \textheight=\initialTextWidth
  
  \global\hsize=\initialTextHeight
  \global\vsize=\initialTextWidth

  \fancyheadoffset{0pt}
  \fancyfootoffset{0pt}
  \fancyhfoffset{0pt}

}{
  \newpage
  \pagestyle{fancy}

  \paperwidth=\initialPaperWidth
  \paperheight=\initialPaperHeight
  \pdfpagewidth=\initialPaperWidth

  \textwidth=\initialTextWidth
  \textheight=\initialTextHeight

  \global\hsize=\initialTextWidth
  \global\vsize=\initialTextHeight

  \fancyheadoffset{0pt}
  \fancyfootoffset{0pt}
  \fancyhfoffset{0pt}
  
}


\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{landscape}

  \lipsum
  \lipsum

\end{landscape}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

all your settings such as \paperwidth=\initialPaperWidth in the end code will be discarded at the end of the enviornment before being used. You could look at (or use) the landscape environment from  pdflscape or lscape packages.

you also want to do \clearpage (again) after changing the page size and page style

using pdflscape i get a landscape page but the header is not rotated. using `lscape i get a portrait page with header/footer and only the content is rotated :/

well ok but still you need to change the settings before setting the page style

like at the end  of the enddef of \newenvironment? i tried the end, the beginning, begindef. Not sure where to put it. I also tried in my document

As far as I can tell you want something like this (copying some settings from lscape)

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
% \usepackage{showframe}


\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{Some Header Text}
\fancyfoot[R]{!!!\thepage!!!}% just to make it show up 

\newcommand{\newvar}[2]{%%%
  \newlength#1%%%
  \setlength#1{#2}%%%
}

\newvar{\initialPaperWidth}{\paperwidth}
\newvar{\initialPaperHeight}{\paperheight}
\newvar{\initialTextWidth}{\textwidth}
\newvar{\initialTextHeight}{\textheight}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{landscape}{%%%
  \clearpage
  \paperwidth=\initialPaperHeight
  \paperheight=\initialPaperWidth
  \pdfpagewidth=\initialPaperHeight
  \pdfpageheight=\initialPaperWidth
  \textwidth=\initialTextHeight
  \textheight=\initialTextWidth
  \fancyheadoffset{0pt}%%%
  \fancyfootoffset{0pt}%%%
  \fancyhfoffset{0pt}%%%
  \pagestyle{fancy}%%%
  \vsize=\textheight
  \@colroom=\vsize
  \@colht\vsize
  \hsize=\textwidth
\clearpage
}{%%%
  \clearpage
  \textwidth=\initialTextWidth
  \textheight=\initialTextHeight
    \global\pdfpagewidth=\initialPaperWidth
  \global\pdfpageheight=\initialPaperHeight
  \global\@colht=\textheight
  \global\vsize=\textheight
  \global\@colroom=\textheight
  \pagestyle{fancy}%%%
\clearpage
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{landscape}

  \lipsum
  \lipsum

\end{landscape}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}


Work's like a charm. Thx

I think you forgot a \makeatother.

@PietervanOostrum well I could add one:-)
